# Recursive Depth First Search in Python

Tags: python, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

So I've been trying to implement depth first search recursion in python. In my program I'm aiming to return the parent array. (the parent of the vertices in the graph)

```
def dfs_tree(graph, start):
    a_list = graph.adjacency_list
    parent = [None]*len(a_list)
    state = [False]*len(a_list)
    state[start] = True

    for item in a_list[start]:
        if state[item[0]] == False:    
            parent[item[0]] = start
            dfs_tree(graph, item[0])
    state[start] = True

    return parent
```

It says that the maximum recursion depth is reached. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for such behavior as I can see is the re-initialization of `state` (and `parent`) arrays on each recursion call. You need to initialize them only once for each traverse. The common approach for that is to add these arrays to function arguments list, initialize them with `None`'s, and replacing with lists on first call:

```
def dfs_tree(graph, start, parent=None, state=None):
    a_list = graph.adjacency_list
    if parent is None:
        parent = [None]*len(a_list)
    if state is None:
        state = [False]*len(a_list)
    state[start] = True

    for item in a_list[start]:
        if state[item[0]] == False:    
            parent[item[0]] = start
            dfs_tree(graph, item[0], parent, state)
    state[start] = True

    return parent
```

After that change algorithm seems to be correct. But the problem [mentioned by Esdes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161067/756261) is still there. If you want to correctly traverse graphs of size `n` you need to do `sys.setrecursionlimit(n + 10)`. `10` there stands for the maximum number of nested function calls outside `dfs_tree` including hidden initial calls. You should increase it if you need.

But it's not a final solution. Python interpreter have some limit on stack memory itself, which differs depending on OS and some settings. So if you increase `recursionlimit` above some threshold you would start to get "segmentation fault" errors when the interpreter's memory limit is exceeded. I don't remember exactly the approximate value of this threshold but it looks to be about 3000 calls. I don't have an interpreter now to check.

In this case you may want to consider re-implementing you algorithm to non-recursive version using stack or try to change python interpreter's stack memory limit.

**P.S.** You may want to change `if state[item[0]] == False:` to `if not state[item[0]]:`. Comparing booleans is usually considered as a bad practice.

Comment: thanks, just what i needed. i'm gonna try and work on the points you've mentioned :)

Answer (score -1):

To fix this error just increase the default recursion depth limit like this (by default it is 1000):

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

Comment: and how would you fix that when it gets blown?